# Right click in Silverlight 3 out of browser

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

In Silverlight 2 it was possible to use the browser DOM to get right click events - of course that's not possible for a Silverlight 3 OOB app.  Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand current UX trends, right-click is considered harmful. Consider click-and-hold (which is common in touch interfaces) with a tooltip letting the user know it's available (cf: Chrome's *Back* button) or floating a mini-toolbar over the control on mouse-hover.

Comment: Good point, never thought about that (especially with the growing number of mobile devices).

Answer (score 0):

Does http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2009/05/09/Adding-rightclick-to-Silverlight.aspx help you?

Also check http://silverlight.pastebin.com/f5a2e59cd

Comment: Those both look like they rely on being in-browser (via DOM hacks), which doesn't help answer the question.

Comment: I agree, they both appear to require the DOM.

Comment: Yes, you both are right. I guess the reason they do not support it; is to support touch screens devices or mobile phones which do not have double click or right click. If they ever want to support iPhone; then I would support them to continue without right click!

Comment: Check out SL 4.0, They have added the right click support now :)